# Battery issues on a Lenovo Ideapad Z460 running Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, battery

I've been using Ubuntu 13.10 on my Lenovo for more than 5 months without a problem. Yesterday I disconnected the AC adapter to take the laptop with me to the couch and it simply shut down. So I reconnected it to at least be able to check what was going on and, to my surprise, the OS seems to be recognizing the battery as it always did. This is the result of dumping `upower`:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ACAD
  native-path:          ACAD
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 26 Jan 2014 08:48:06 PM EST (757 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    online:             yes

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               COMPAL
  model:                PABAS024
  serial:               3658Q
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 26 Jan 2014 09:00:40 PM EST (3 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes

  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    energy:              23.99 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         31.16 Wh
    energy-full-design:  48.84 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             11.848 V
    percentage:          76%
    capacity:            63.8002%
    technology:          lithium-ion

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.9.22
  can-suspend:     yes
  can-hibernate:   no
  on-battery:      no
  on-low-battery:  no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  is-docked:       no
```

Yet, I still can't use the battery... It's as if the OS knew the battery was there but couldn't switch to it whenever the AC adapter is disconnected. The battery icon, by the way, is always full.

Specs:
Lenovo Ideapad Z460
Intel Core i5 CPU M 480 @ 2.67GHz × 4
Ubuntu 13.10 (64-bit)

Comment: Is it possible that the battery is dead? I have a similar issue on a Lenovo ThinkPad T61: I disconnect the adapter, the battery looks full, but the laptop runs out of juice in 10-15min. I suspect that the battery is simply too old. Have you tried unplugging the adapter while on Windows (if you have that) and see if the same issue occurs?